# Swift. How to edit two different label in TableViewCell for each cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have TableView which has cells with 2 label. I want to set value for both label during load operation. However, I have no access to both labels.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let fr = fractionList[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FrictionCell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.textLabel?.text = fr.fraction
    //cell.textLabel?.text = fr.decimal
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: fr.color ?? "#FFFFFF")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't use `textLabel`, you would use whatever properties you are using to hold the label references

Answer (score 0):

you can't have two labels with the same name so you can rename the outlet for your labels to have two outlets in your cell `SwipeTableViewCell` :

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblFractionOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDecimalOutlet: UILabel!
```

and then you can access them in function `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.lblFractionOutlet.text = fr.fraction
cell.lblDecimalOutlet.text = fr.decimal
```

I hope it will work with you...

Comment: thank you for effort. I can't use outlet in this case, because outlets are not invalid in repeating contents. I want to add different fraction and decimals on every cell in table view.

Comment: But I think this will work with any cell and with different actions